# std::find with type T** vs T*[N]

Tags: stl, find, command-line-arguments, c++

I prefer to work with `std::string` but I like to figure out what is going wrong here.

I am unable to understand out why `std::find` isn't working properly for type `T**` even though pointer arithmetic works on them correctly. Like -

```
std::cout << *(argv+1) << "\t" <<*(argv+2) << std::endl;
```

But it works fine, for the types `T*[N]`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main( int argc, const char ** argv )
{   
    std::cout << *(argv+1) << "\t" <<*(argv+2) << std::endl;

    const char ** cmdPtr = std::find(argv+1, argv+argc, "Hello") ;

    const char * testAr[] = { "Hello", "World" };
    const char ** testPtr = std::find(testAr, testAr+2, "Hello");

    if( cmdPtr == argv+argc )
        std::cout << "String not found" << std::endl;

    if( testPtr != testAr+2 )
        std::cout << "String found: " << *testPtr << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Arguments passed: Hello World

Output:

> Hello World
>   String not found
>   String found: Hello

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing types of `char const*` amounts to pointing to the addresses. The address of `"Hello"` is guaranteed to be different unless you compare it to another address of the string literal `"Hello"` (in which case the pointers *may* compare equal). Your `compare()` function compares the characters being pointed to.

Comment: Could you now check the second case.

Comment: There isn't any guarantee that string literals get the same address. They may or they may not. Some compilers are quite thorough to share string literals in on translation units, others are not.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you're comparing the pointer values themselves and not what they're pointing to. And the constant "Hello" doesn't have the same address as the first element of `argv`.

Try using:

```
const char ** cmdPtr = std::find(argv+1, argv+argc, std::string("Hello")) ;
```

`std::string` knows to compare contents and not addresses.

For the array version, the compiler can fold all literals into a single one, so every time "Hello" is seen throughout the code it's really the same pointer. Thus, comparing for equality in

```
const char * testAr[] = { "Hello", "World" };
const char ** testPtr = std::find(testAr, testAr+2, "Hello");
```

yields the correct result

Comment: But why is it working for the character array of pointer types.

Comment: Because the compiler probably folds all identical literals into a single one. So all the "Hello" literals you have in your code are really the same pointer